# Google Ortools - trouble with routing example

Tags: or-tools

I am having an odd issue with Google Ortools vehicle routing example, found here:

https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing

Using Windows 10, and Python 3.6...

When executing the full program code provided in the link above, the program freezes up and exits. Command line provides the following:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0502 21:33:22.115679  7972 search.cc:2658] Check failed: step > 0 (0 vs. 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I have honed the code causing the freeze down to this line of code:

```
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```

I am certain I have the library properly installed because other examples of the program have run successfully. I attempted to use Visual Studio, and even went so far as to disable my second GPU.

I am wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and possibly knows how to fix. Thank You.

Comment: no errors for me. how do you know the problem is with this line you pointed out?

Comment: Was certain because I commented every line of code after that line and it froze. Then commented that line and program ran.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was solved as follows:

Original model on google's website creates the following variable:

```
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
```

I had changed to:

```
search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultModelParameters()
```

But the required change should be:

```
search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultSearchParameters()
```